# WHats wrong with this code for palindrome of a string array

Tags: java, string, palindrome

Write a method isPalindrome that accepts an array of Strings as its argument and returns true if that array is a palindrome (if it reads the same forwards as backwards) and /false if not. For example, the array {"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "gamma", "beta", "alpha"} is a palindrome, so passing that array to your method would return true. Arrays with zero or one element are considered to be palindromes.

```
    public boolean  isPalindrome(String[] str){
        for (int i =0;i<str.length;i++){
           if (str[i]!=str[str.length-1-i])
                return false;
      }
     return true;
     }
```

It fails for the inputs according to a practice website answers.

isPalindrome({"aay", "bee", "cee", "cee", "bee", "aay"})

isPalindrome({"aay", "bee", "cee", "cee", "bee", "aay"})

Comment: In addition to using equals in the comparation as its said in the answers, you could use *i<str.length/2), because you are comparing array[i] with array[n-1-i] and later comparing array[n-1-i] with array[i].

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: write `str[i].equals(str[str.length-1-i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` is an array of `String`s.

To compare the value of `String`s, you have to use `String.equals` - the `==` operator compares the identity of the string and not the value itself.

`public boolean isPalindrome(String[] str){
    for (int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
       if (!str[i].equals(str[str.length - i - 1])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 2):

see [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

You have to use the equals method, not the = operator for comparing strings in java.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are treated like other objects - comapring with `!=` compares the references, not the values. For value comparison you need to use `String.equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

This code is comparing strings using `==`, which performs an identity comparison on objects. You need to compare strings using `string1.equals(string2)` to check for content equality.

The method fails for the input `isPalindrome({"a", "aa".substring(1)})`, because the two strings are equal, but not identical.

For more details, check out [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) which contains some more examples.

Answer (score 2):

try this instead `if (!str[i].equals(str[str.length-1-i]))`